# Django don't get the good URI when using nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

When using nginx as a proxy to the request, django continue to believe that my site url is `127.0.0.1:myport`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your settings.py:

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
```

It will tell django to use the X-FORWARDED-HOST header that nginx pass.